# Show that σ(Tv)=Range(v)

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T_{v}:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ be the multiplication operator $(T_{v}f)(x):=v(x)f(x)$, where $v \in C[0,1]$. 
Show that $\sigma(T_{v})=$Range$(v)$.

Let $\lambda \in \sigma(T_{v})$, then $(T_{v}-\lambda)f(x)=0$ and so we have $(v(x)-\lambda )f(x)=0$ . This leads to $v(x)=\lambda$ if $f\neq0$. Then $\lambda=v\in $ Range$(v)$ which shows $\sigma(T_{v})\subset$ Range$(v)$.

I am not sure about the proof  because  $\lambda $ might not be eigenvalue.
Is not $\lambda $ eigenvalue ? If yes or no why ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't it $T_v(f)(x) = v(x)f(x)$?

Comment: Yes i am sorry I have editted it.

Comment: but range of $T_v$ is a subset of $C[0,1]$ not of real numbers. So what does your main question means then?

Comment: Does $f$ has to be different from $0$ ?

Comment: If range of $T_v$ is a subset of C[0,1] is not real numbers , What happens ?  I dont know. if you explain, it will be good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda\in v[0,1]$, then $T-\lambda I$ cannot be invertible because all functions in $(T-\lambda I)C[0,1]$ vanish at the point where $v(x)=\lambda$, which prevents the range of $T-\lambda I$ from being full. Indeed, the range is contained in the null space of the continuous linear functional that evaluates functions at $x$.

On the other hand, if $\lambda\notin v[0,1]$, then $R(\lambda)=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and is given by
$$
               R(\lambda)f = \frac{1}{v-\lambda}f.
$$
This is a bounded operator because the range of $v$ is compact, and $\lambda$ is not in that range. And $(T-\lambda I)R(\lambda)f=R(\lambda)(T-\lambda I)f=f$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$.

There is no reason that $\lambda\in v[0,1]$ is an eigenvalue because $(v-\lambda)f\equiv 0$ may not hold for all $x$, unless $f\equiv 0$. If $v=\lambda$ on a non-trival interval $[a,b]\subseteq [0,1]$ where $a\ne b$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, and the eigenspace is infinite dimensional.